# Finding difference between two consecutive enteries of a table using SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a log table in which requests and response are getting logged and if one row is for request then the next row will be for response. There is a time column in which their time is getting recorded. I want to write a query which can subtract the time of two consecutive rows (i.e request and response)  and then give me only those req and responses between which the time difference is more then 4 seconds.

Table is like this

```
Sr.no     Type     time
1         Req      2015-03-31 02:26:36.330000
2         Res      2015-03-31 02:26:36.330000
3         Req      2015-03-31 03:18:30.780000
4         Res      2015-03-31 03:18:30.820000
```

Comment: Given your sample data, neither row would be returned. It may be helpful to update it with some information that can be returned, and show the results you're expecting from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that `srno` has an incremental value with no gaps, then you can use a join like this:

```
select lreq.*, lres.time,
       timestampdiff('second', lreq.time, lres.time) as diff_in_secs
from logs lreq join
     logs lres
     on lreq.srno = lres.srno - 1 and
        lreq.type = 'req' and
        lres.type = 'res'
having diff_in_secs > 4;
```

If the above conditions are not true, you can do something similar with a correlated subquery.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks your answer is really helpful. It solves my purpose perfectly.